# borderRadius not working during each image load in image carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native, carousel, react-native-ios

I have created a horizontal image carousel and want all corners of the carousel to be rounded. `borderRadius` and `overflow:'hidden'` seem to work for the images but when the next image is loading, the corners show up until it is loaded. The carousel is set to load to successive images in a loop every 2 seconds.

Here's the part that renders:

```
render() {
        const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
        return (
            <View
                style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 20 }}
                onLayout={event => {
                    this.setState({
                        carouselWidth: event.nativeEvent.layout.width
                    })
                }}
            >
                <ScrollView
                    horizontal
                    pagingEnabled
                    onMomentumScrollEnd={this.setSelectedIndex}
                    ref={this.scrollRef}
                    //contentContainerStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }}
                >
                    {images.map(image => (

                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            source={image}
                            style={styles.backgroundImage}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View >
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundImage: {
        height: '100%',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
        resizeMode: "stretch",
        borderRadius: 20,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }
});
```